# RHEL: Adjust Screen Resolution of Virtual Box

Tags: rhel, virtualbox, virtual-machine

Am using Redhat Enterprise Linux 7.3 with kernel version of `3.10.0-514.el7` below mentioned kernel with Redhat Enterprise Linux on top of Oracle Virtual box 5.1.10, the guest OS display is not fit to my screen, I tried "Insert Guest Additions CD", and no result, see the below screenshot.

How can I solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: try `yum update` then  `yum install kernel-devel gcc` and reinstall the guest additions

Comment: @Dababi, ok Sir let me do it now, I'll comment here the result

Comment: @Dababi, no change still it saying Failed to setup service vboxAdd

Comment: ok then try to install `yum install kernel-devel-$(uname -r)` and `dkms` packages and reinstall guest additions if it doesn't work you can look at the /var/log/vboxadd-install log to see what is missing.

Comment: @Dababi, appreciated your support, thank you very much; it is solved, please post the comment as answer to mark this question answered.

Comment: Ok i m glad it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Login to a root shell. The installation of guest additions will require the building of kernel modules. So you will need to install DKMS (Dynamic Kernel Module Support) that is used to simplify kernel upgrades (If DKMS is not used the Guest Additions will need to be reinstalled after every kernel update) and  `kernel-devel` packages using these commands:

```
yum update
yum install dkms
yum install kernel-devel gcc
yum install kernel-devel-$(uname -r)
```

then you can install guest additions from the device tool.